# A, Buzz, C, D, E, Fizz, G

Tags: code-golf, string

A simple FizzBuzz using strings.

**Given**

- 1 word or phrase (string)
- 2 unique characters

**Output**

The word or phrase with each occurrence of the first character replaced with fizz and each of the second character replaced with buzz

**Rules**

- The first letter in both Fizz and Buzz must remain capitalized
- For the rest of the words fizz and buzz, you must match the case of the replaced character (if no case then keep lowercase)
- If given characters are not in the phrase, output the original phrase

**Test Cases**

```
Given: Hello, h, l
Output: FIZZeBuzzBuzzo

Given: test, a, b
Output: test

Given: PCG rocks!,  , !
PCGFizzrocksBuzz

Given: This
Is
SPARTA!, 
, S
Output: ThiBuzzFizzIBuzzFizzBUZZPARTA!

Given: FizzBuzz, a, b
Output: FizzBUZZuzz
```

This is code-golf so the shortest code, in bytes, wins!

**Note**

Technically handling the newline case (This Is SPARTA!) is a part of the challenge. However, I will not void an answer for not including it, as it is very challenging or even impossible in some languages.

Comment: `you must match the case of the replaced character` and `Input is not case sensitive` seem to contradict each other.

Comment: @GregMartin ah thank you, i was trying to say that the 2 characters as input are case sensitive (ex. A means the same as a)

Comment: `ThiBuzzFizzIBuzzFizzBUZZPARTA` is missing a final exclamation mark.

Comment: Are we supposed to support inputs such as `aa, a, f`? What would be the expected output? `BUZZizzBUZZizz`, `FizzFizz`, or both allowed at our option?

Comment: @Amauld Based on the last test case, I'd say it should output `FizzFizz`.

Comment: @Arnauld FizzFizz

Comment: What characters can appear in the phrase? Any ASCII? Or just letters/typical punctuation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 34 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Œl=€⁹Œl¤ȧ€"“¡Ṭ4“Ụp»o"/ȯ"Œu⁹Œln$T¤¦
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@390Uo7to6Y1jxp3AlmHlpxYDuQoPWqYc2jhw51rTICMh7uXFBzana@kf2K90tFJpRCFeSohh5YcWvb//3@u4P8hGZnFXJ7FXMEBjkEhjooA)**

#### How?

```
Œl=€⁹Œl¤ȧ€"“¡Ṭ4“Ụp»o"/ȯ"Œu⁹Œln$T¤¦ - Main link: characters, string
Œl                                 - lowercase the characters
       ¤                           - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
    ⁹                              -     right argument, the string
     Œl                            -     lowercase
  =€                               - equals (vectorises) for €ach (a list of 2 lists that identify the indexes of the string matching the characters regardless of case)
           “¡Ṭ4“Ụp»                - dictionary strings ["Fizz", "Buzz"]
          "                        - zip with
        ȧ€                         -     logical and (non-vectorising) for €ach (replace the 1s with the words)
                     /             - reduce with:
                    "              -     zip with:
                   o               -         logical or (vectorises) (make one list of zeros and the words)
                                   - implicit right argument, string
                       "           - zip with:
                      ȯ            -     logical or (non-vectorising) (replace the zeros with the original characters from the string)
                                 ¦ - apply...
                        Œu         -     uppercase
                                   - ...to the indexes (the words at indexes):
                                ¤  -     nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
                          ⁹        -         right argument, the string
                              $    -         last two links as a monad (i.e. the string on both sides):
                           Œl      -             lowercase
                             n     -             not equals (vectorises)
                               T   -         truthy indexes (the indexes of the capital letters in the string)
```

Comment: +1, Thank you for using the newline case. That makes this the first entirely correct submission

Answer (score 6):

### [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.6/), <s>180</s> <s>174</s> <s>168</s> <s>160</s> 152 bytes

```python
from sys import*
J=''.join
L=str.lower
s,a,b=J(stdin).split(', ')
print(J('FBFBiuIUzzZZzzZZ'[L(k)==L(b)::2][k!=L(k)::2]*(L(k)in L(a+b))or k for k in s))
```

This is just a more golfed version of [Stephen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/113295/39211)'s answer, in Python 3. This chips away 42% of his bytes. Python 2 would save one byte on the print, but such is the price of progress. This handles newlines properly.

Thanks to Blckknight for saving 8 bytes on input.

Comment: What is the `fileinput` modules used for?

Comment: @ValyrioAccount, [fileinput.input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) overrides the built-in input method. It enables inputs with newlines.

Comment: How about `from sys import*` and `s,a,b=J(stdin).split(', ')` to save a few characters?

Answer (score 4):

## Python, 109 bytes

```python
lambda s,w:"".join([c,"Fizz","Buzz","BUZZ","FIZZ"][-~w.lower().find(c.lower())*-~(-2*c.isupper())]for c in s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#PY47D4JAEIT7@xXLVnvkoLA0sVATlcSC@GhECjwhniJHOAyJhX8dj/NR7E5mstlvismxL7P76ZyBEd0YMbxqVVEiBS7U84kCZ4@P7A8HK4vISpoEry4sdZc3xMNCVWeSP8v94EXByJehMo@6dlFa6AYkqAoM79vctAYmkBCu8rLU9ulljVwQxvMlNFrejIcCEDwbArka3w7Zyd0h7i7KsMiwbTzd7KaeTYQdtrWLp2ygDZQB6GhjBnWjqpYGx3@mIN/5f8D7Nw)

---

Takes the two characters as a single string

*Edit:
Added testcase to TIO link, newline works too*

Answer (score 2):

## Bash 4.4 + GNU sed, <s>70</s> <s>228</s> <s>222</s> 227 bytes

```
IFS=;alias e=echo;K=`sed $([[ $2 != '
' ]]&&e "s/${2,}/Fizz/g;s/${2^}/FIZZ/g"||:)$([[ $3 != '
' ]]&&e ";s/${3,}/Buzz/g;s/${3^}/BUZZ/g"||:)<<<"$1"`;[[ $2 = '
'||$3 = '
' ]]&&e ${K//$'\n'/`[[ $2 = '
' ]]&&e Fizz||e Buzz`}||e "$K"
```

Apparently `alias e=echo` throws an error if referenced in Bash 4.3 or below, the version TIO is apparently using. Therefore, the longer and equivalent Bash 4.3 code is given in the below TIO test suite for the sake of testing. This passes all of the test cases, so that is nice.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#Zc69CoMwFAXgPU8RQzAttITqqA46COJSql20SooVddEhdNH42J3TqP3DjgfO/c6VgR85VugwXt4g3qQpxAbUHEgAgVmm62VRdxBxigdjN1K/6XtaWXPMVQyShFZIiKWFtgtg/gPziakE7/4RTCV455Vg2zbCB8Ss5ZPZEUKRKxEPIaWYXFpC2U/1W5hefbHTJhvfGzhEUsq4bjgIOIiO7il2NQlk9Gi7fXEt6vIJ)

Comment: @thedarkwanderer Now it should. Sorry that it took a bit long to fix.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <strike>271</strike>, 261 bytes

```python
import fileinput as f
a=''
for m in f.input():a+=m
a=a.split(', ')
l=L=list(a[0])
for i in range(0,len(a[0])):
 j,k=l[i].lower(),l[i].istitle()
 if j==a[1].lower():
  L[i]='FIZZ'if k else'Fizz'
 elif j==a[2].lower():
  L[i]='BUZZ'if k else'Buzz'
print''.join(L)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#bcwxC8IwEIbhPb/itkswlOooZHEQhK4uLQ4RErl6TUuaIvjna1pRENxyvN@Tmbqhjwk8saMwTAnsCF5Ygyh8H6EDCuCLNUm1txvT5WiLcWBKEjWgEmwqwzQmaZvyolZGC4s23JwsNbvwTmovoNV3ww1dCu4fLkql1yNrSuykEkAeWmNss/1OsoIqrwweT3WNeXAHx6PDIz2fKPL7Y3Z/zOH8Yw7TYoZIISEWbU9BVmqel6@WpMFquL4A)

Wow this one was a doozie! It turns out python won't accept multi-line inputs so `fileinput` must be used.

edit: should pass all cases now :)

Comment: Definite +1 for handling the case with newlines! Not many are able to incorporate that

Comment: You could save 3 bytes by doing something like `import fileinput as f` ... `for m in f.input():`

Comment: @Caleb Thanks for the suggestion! it should pass all tests now

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB/[Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>106</s> <s>102</s> 111 bytes

```matlab
@(a,b,c)regexprep(a,num2cell([lower([b c]) upper([b c]) '1234']),{'2','4','1','3','FIZZ','Fizz','BUZZ','Buzz'})
```

This could probably be optimised further.

It uses a simple Regex replacement. However an intermediate step is required by replacing the input characters with numbers first. This is so that if the second input replace letter was contained in `Fizz` that the `Fizz` doesn't then get replaced when the next regex is performed.

This of course assumes there are no numbers in the input. However given the question says the input is a word or phrase I feel that this is an acceptable assumption.

The code will handle new lines in the input correctly.

You can [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#RY2xCsIwFEV/5W0vgQwm7QdIB1FwdWnIkMaHFmIbUoJS8dvjq4vD4XKGe2/dC68GFWSmG71SpsQ@lYcJFKOwcX5SFnaA4CSUlP6C2jQtOqneaFBhy2imYQ6nvt9iXFeO7vKzrrB9ZPXTIiweeX1G0DvA8zjRAj4T@LjdXdEpvHMjoqxf)

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 92 bytes

Takes input as a string and an array of two characters. Supports newlines.

```js
f=(s,[a,b],r='Fizz')=>a?f(s.replace(RegExp(a,'gi'),m=>m<'a'?r.toUpperCase():r),[b],'Buzz'):s
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=(s,[a,b],r='Fizz')=>a?f(s.replace(RegExp(a,'gi'),m=>m<'a'?r.toUpperCase():r),[b],'Buzz'):s

console.log(f("Hello", ['h', 'l']))
console.log(f("test", ['a', 'b']))
console.log(f("PCG rocks!", [' ', '!']))
console.log(f(`This
Is
SPARTA!`, [`
`, 'S']))
console.log(f("FizzBuzz", ['a', 'b']))
```

Answer (score 2):

### [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 135 + 1(r flag) = 136 bytes

By default, a sed script is executed as many times as there are input lines. To handle multi-line input, I use a loop to append all possible remaining lines to the first, without starting a new cycle.

```sed
:r
$!N
$!br
s:, (.), (.):;\u\1FIZZ;\l\1Fizz;\u\2BUZZ;\l\2Buzz:
s:^:,:
:
s:,(.)(.*;\1)(...)(.):\3,\4\2\3\4:
s:,(.):\1,:
/,;.F/!t
s:,.*::
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/sed#NYuxCoMwEED3fEWEDirXSKLTZdJBcCml2kWODp0MlFoSXfLxTZOWDnf3eNwLaNkhO8W5W@YQeC6K70JNO8l@mGdNjwjG@2RUd/0Z1e3eY0xuCMgSQKxyUWqS8YjEBVIN1JCimpr/C5KMQQVa9FW2JSlKxBCmxTg2ODae28vUZsAZ8PG9vjazPl042g8)**

The replacement table used on line 4, needs to be in that exact order, i.e. 'Fizz' and 'Buzz' after their upper-case forms. This is because the sed regex `.*`, used during the table lookup, is greedy. If the current char needed to be replaced is not a letter (no case), then the lowercase string is needed (matched last).

Since sed has no data types, I use a character delimiter to iterate a string. It will mark my current position and in a loop I shift it from left to right. Fortunately, I can use `,` for this, since it is the input data delimiter.

**Explanation:**

```sed
:r                                                 # reading loop
$!N                                                # append next input line
$!br                                               # repeat till EOF
s:, (.), (.):;\u\1FIZZ;\l\1Fizz;\u\2BUZZ;\l\2Buzz: # create replacement table
s:^:,:                                             # append my string delimiter
:                                                  # main loop
s:,(.)(.*;\1)(...)(.):\3,\4\2\3\4:                 # apply char replacement, if any
s:,(.):\1,:                                        # shift delimiter to right
/,;.F/!t                                           # repeat till end of string
s:,.*::                                            # print only the final string
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - 25 bytes

```
sXzsrBQ1scL2rB"FizzBuzz"1
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sXzsrBQ1scL2rB%22FizzBuzz%221&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22hl%22%0AHello%0A%22ab%22%0Atest%0A%22+%21%22%0APCG+rocks%21%0A%22ab%22%0AFizzBuzz&debug=0&input_size=2).

Comment: A capital as one of the characters seems to cause problems - `"Hl", Hello` does not capitalise the output correctly and `"hL", Hello` does not substitute the `l`s.

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 114 bytes

```
u=Data.Char.toUpper
p[f,b]x|f==u x="Fizz"|b==u x="Buzz"|2>1=[x]
q x y|u y<y=x|2>1=u<$>x
r x=concatMap$q=<<p(u<$>x)
```

`r` takes the fizz and buzz characters as a 2 element list as the first argument, and the input string as the second argument. Newlines and unicode should be handled appropriately, although the function is unfortunately not total (allowing for invalid inputs saved 5 bytes).

Comment: `u=Data.Char.toUpper` only works in ghci as far as I know. In standard Haskell you need the `import`. However you should be able to save some bytes by using `=<<` instead of `concatMap`.

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 94 bytes

```
a=ToLowerCase;b=ToUpperCase;StringReplace@{a@#->"Fizz",b@#->"FIZZ",a@#2->"Buzz",b@#2->"BUZZ"}&
```

Anonymous function. Takes two strings as input and returns a function which takes a string as input and returns a string as output as output. It must be called in the format `prog["c1", "c2"]["s"]`, where `"s"` is the target string and `"c1"` and `"c2"` are the two characters. Could probably be golfed further.